# Trigger that Auto Updates field on parent when child record is updated

Tags: apex, trigger

Is there a way to automatically update the Callable_Contacts__c field on the Account object when a related Contact is updated?

```
trigger CallableContacts on Account (before insert, before update) {
    for(Account acc : Trigger.new) {
        //Search for related Contacts
        List<Contact> callableContacts = [SELECT  Id, 
                                            Phone, 
                                            Account.Name 
                                            FROM Contact 
                                            WHERE Account.Id = :acc.Id];
        System.debug('Callable contacts found: ' + callableContacts.size());

        //For each contact, check whether the Phone Number field is filled in and increment the callable contacts field on Account
        Integer count = 0; 
        if(!callableContacts.isEmpty()) {
            for(Contact con : callableContacts) {
                if(con.Phone != null) {
                    count = count + 1;
                    acc.Callable_Contacts__c = count;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "when a related Contact is **updated**", that means your trigger point is at the Contact object, so your trigger should be Contact trigger (after update).

Answer (score 0):

You can very well do this using a Process Builder if there is no existing trigger on the Contact object. When configuring the immediate actions, you can select the option "Select a record related to the Contact" where there is an option to update the fields on the Account object and also add specific conditions when it should be updated. Given the chance, it is better to go with a configuration approach rather than customization.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "automatically", but the most accurate answer is probably no.

There will be DML and a trigger involved somewhere. The DML-less update feature of before insert/update triggers only works on the object the trigger is defined on (not on related records) and further only on SObject instances contained within `trigger.new` or `trigger.newMap`

If we had the ability to create a rollup summary field to summarize Contacts related to an Account (which we don't), then an update to a Contact would automatically cause the Account to undergo an implicit dml update.

You'd then need a trigger on Account to do the actual summarization.

Since we can't make such a rollup summary field, you'd need to either:

- have 2 triggers (one on `Contact` to perform a dml update on the related accounts so you could get into the trigger on `Account` to do the actual work)
- have a single trigger on `Contact` that handles updating your count on `Account`

The single trigger on `Contact` would use a SOQL query using the `GROUP BY` clause to do the heavy lifting. Something like

```java
// this is pseudo-code, and will not work if you just copy/paste it
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

Map<Id, Account> accountsMap = new Map<Id, Account>();

for(contacts in trigger.new){
    // gather account ids for our query
    // We also need to default our accounts to a count of 0, otherwise this approach
    //   would not be able to detect when the last contact(s) on an Account no longer
    //   satisfy your criteria
    accountIds.add(contact's AccountId);
    accountsMap.put(contact's AccountId, new Account(Id = contact's AccountId, MyCount__c = 0);

}

// SOQL can do the heavy lifting
for(AggregateResult ar :[SELECT AccountId, COUNT(Id) numContacts FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds AND Phone != null GROUP BY AccountId]){
    // Getting data from AggregateResult always uses .get() and needs to be type-cast appropriately
    Account acc = new Account(
        // We can set SObject Ids in the SObject constructor, which allows us to
        //   avoid the need to use another query
        Id = (Id)ar.get('AccountId'),
        // You may or may not need to guard against potential null values
        MyCount__c = (Integer)ar.get('numContacts')
    );

    // put the account into our map
}

// DML inside of loops is as bad as queries inside of loops (arguably worse)
// Now that we're outside of all loops, we can perform the update
update accountMap.values();
```

You could also use [Andrew Fawcett's Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), which in the end will generate a trigger similar to the one in my example. The difference being that the DLRS tool generates the trigger for you and provides a declarative interface.